# Instagram feed with Grid Rotator.js

Tags: jquery, html, feed, instagram

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var userFeed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'user',
    userId: **********,
    accessToken: '*************',
       template: '<a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>'

});

userFeed.run();
$('#instafeed').cycle({
    fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
});
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.gridrotator.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function() {
$( '#instafeed' ).gridrotator( {
                animSpeed : 300,
                animType : 'rotateBottom',
                w320 : {
                    rows : 3,
                    columns : 4
                },
                w240 : {
                    rows : 3,
                    columns : 3
                },
                slideshow : false,
                onhover : true
            } );

    </script>
```

Im trying to create an instagram feed with rotating effect so i used instafeed.js and gridrotator.js but it seems to be not working. I have the instafeed working but not the gridrotator.

Comment: probably best to tag your question with something other than Instagram then. Also, you might want to provide details of exactly what is not working, any errors?

Comment: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

this is the only error i got. Both js are working, instafeed can pull pictures, and gridrotator can shuffle image when i put static html codes there. I think it must echo the instagram images like in php because when you try to view source it the html for the images wont comeout since its pulled thru jquery. Is there a way to make that?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
    clientId: '***********',
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'food',
    resolution: 'standard_resolution',
    sortBy: 'most-recent',
    limit: 60,
    template: '<li class="square-insta"><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a></li>',
    after: function() {
        $( '#ri-grid' ).gridrotator( {
            rows        : 4,
            columns     : 5,
            animType    : 'fadeInOut',
            animSpeed   : 1000,
            interval    : 600,
            step        : 1,
            w320        : {
                rows    : 3,
                columns : 4
            },
            w240        : {
                rows    : 3,
                columns : 4
            }
        } );
    }
});

feed.run();
```

And your HTML:

```
<section class="instagram ri-grid ri-grid-size-2" id="ri-grid">

          <ul id="instafeed">

          </ul>
</section>
```